# Bottom Space on layouts Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I have a parent constraint layout and i am getting bottom Space on each and [Check Image U can see space at bottom even layout constraints are attach to bottom of parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR5ow.png) every layout. However layout I have developed before are all working fine. Below is XML for one of my layouts.[image]

You can see I have attached Constraints to bottom of parent but still I am getting this issue.

Please notice I have changed it to linear as well still the result is same. One strange thing is on Emulator its working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>


        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.schoolber.handler.ChatEventhandlers" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_tag"
            layout="@layout/chat_main_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            bind:handler="@{handler}" />

        <!--        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar-->
        <!--            android:id="@+id/toolbar"-->
        <!--            android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"-->
        <!--            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
        <!--            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
        <!--            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
        <!--            />-->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/greyPortionView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white_four"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_tag" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/chatInboxList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/greyPortionViewSecond"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/greyPortionView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noRecentTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="32dp"
            android:background="@color/white_seven"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_tag"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:textColor="@color/brownish_grey"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
            android:text="No Recent Chat Found"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_chat_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_icon"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shadow"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:translationZ="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/greyPortionViewSecond"
            />



        <View
            android:id="@+id/greyPortionViewSecond"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white_four"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab_messgae" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fab_messgae"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.searchUser()}"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ic_chat"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ic_chat"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ic_chat"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menuchat_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ic_chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/aqua_marine"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="-4sp"
            android:text="@string/chat"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ic_profile_tv"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fab_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> handler.searchUser()}"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ic_profile_tv"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ic_profile_tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ic_profile_tv"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menucontacts_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ic_profile_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/contacts"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="-4sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ic_chat"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: can you show the layout, how it's being displayed?

Comment: Hi i have updated the post

Comment: I think the constraint layout is from end to end but the icons in the bottom are elevated. Please verify if if constraint layout is inflated in the whole screen.

Comment: Yes layout is inflated in whole screen infact if i set background as black whole screen is black.

Comment: Please check the position of noRecentTV see if its properly place during runtime. Maybe try deleting it.

Comment: Checked no success :(

Comment: Ok do one more thing for debugging layouts, enable show layout bounds from developer options, maybe that will give us some ideas where the extra space is coming from

Comment: Tried it on layout bound i have a view on right bottom a box however on layout inspector there is no bottom view below my field

Comment: I tried that layout myself but its working fine.

Comment: Strange i even making this layout as my default layout.

Comment: Hi Borther Its resloved.

Comment: I had bottom padding in my activity Base Class. Thank u soo much

Comment: What version of constraint-layout are you using and what Android version are you testing on?  I just ran into this with v2.0.0-beta2 on Android 6 and 7 (api 23, 24):
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145736492